# Unable to make symbol similar to bowtie or lrtimes

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I wish to write something like this in latex:

[image]

I tried using `\lrtimes` and also `\bowtie`, but none is able to give me the correct output. Also, i had problems getting that `{task1}` below the symbol. For this, i tried using `$\bowtie_\{task_1\}$`, but it didnt give me the required output. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the two triangles should surmount each other?

Comment: May be this works `\underset{\{task 1\}}{\vartriangleright\hspace{-1.7mm}\vartriangleleft}`

Comment: Yes, the lrtimes should do that job. But it is not doing the way it is described in specifications.

Comment: @Manuel: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the answer of @percusse, it's much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\newbowtie}{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\triangleright$\,\cr\,$\triangleleft$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  (\text{Resource}_0 \mathbin{||} \text{Resource}_0)
  \underset{\{\text{task 1}\}}{\bowtie}
  (\text{Processor}_0 \mathbin{||} \text{Processor}_0)
\]

\[
  (\text{Resource}_0 \mathbin{||} \text{Resource}_0)
  \underset{\{\text{task 1}\}}{\newbowtie}
  (\text{Processor}_0 \mathbin{||} \text{Processor}_0)
\]
\end{document}
```

The above symbol creation uses `\ooalign` which overlays elements on top of one another. For a quick course in `\ooalign`, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](http://goo.gl/pkzNr).

Comment: `\ooalign` here? A sledgehammer indeed. :)

Comment: What do `\ooalign` and `\cr` do?

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski: I've added a reference which gives a quick lesson on `\ooalign`.

Answer (score 7):

You could try defining a new command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\mytie}{\mathrel{\rhd\mspace{-10mu}\lhd}}
\begin{document}

$A \mytie B$

$A \underset{\text{task}}{\mytie} B$

\end{document}
```

I've changed the definition from what I first posted because when I tried stacking the relation, the arrows didn't match up as desired.

[image]

Comment: The `\mbox` serves no purpose: just `{\rhd\mspace{-10mu}\lhd}` (notice the additional braces) will do. But also `\mathrel` would be good: `\newcommand{\mytie}{\mathrel{\rhd\mspace{-10mu}\lhd}}` (the argument of `\mathrel` makes a subformula, so the additional braces are not needed any more).

Comment: @egreg.  (For a solution that omits the `\mathrel`) Why does that work?  I tried your suggestion.  If I don't use the parentheses the `mspace` doesn't work as desired.  With the parentheses it does.  What's happening there?

Comment: @A.Ellett -- not egreg, but ... `\mspace` is defined (in `amsmath`) to take an argument, hence requiring the braces.  the tex primitive on which it relies is `\mskip`, which would need no braces.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I understand why it's `\mspace{-10mu}`.  But what I don't understand is why `{\rhd\mspace{-10mu}\lhd}` and `\rhd\mspace{-10mu}\lhd` behave differently.  Maybe that's what you were trying to explain to me.  But I'm still not getting something.

Comment: @A.Ellett Without the braces, the nature of `\rhd` as binary operation shows up: in `$a \rhd\mspace{-10mu}\lhd b$` you have the same situation as in `$a++b$` (the kerning doesn't influence the automatic spacings), which gives an undesired result. With the braces, you are making a subformula consisting of two binary operations, which become ordinary atoms by rule.

Answer (score 6):

You can further scale up/down for your taste. But please consider making words not to be typeset with mathstyle. It's unnecessary difficulty for the reader.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\mytie}[1]{
\mathop{\vartriangleright\!\!\!\vartriangleleft}\limits_{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\[
(\text{Resource}_0 \| \text{Resource}_0) \mytie{\{\text{\emph{task }}1\} }(\text{Processor}_0 \| \text{Processor}_0 )
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd put the `\mathop` (necessary for the subscript) inside a `\mathrel`. Instead of `\!\!\!` why not a single `\mkern-9mu`?

Comment: @egreg Because I forgot that again (and again....) :) For the kerning issue, I was just suggestive since it needs scaling up first in my opinion.

Comment: And the `\mathop` isn't really necessary, for `\underset` is probably more practical, unless *all* instances of `\mytie` need to be subscripted.